# Account balance not updating

Tags: transactions, testnets

I tried to start a private ethereum testnet on my laptop. Then created 2 accounts and did transaction from the 1st account to the 2nd one.But he balance is not updating in the 2nd account. Here are the following details:

myGenesis.json :

```
    {
   "config": {
      "chainId": 1998,
      "homesteadBlock": 0,
      "eip155Block": 0,
      "eip158Block": 0,
      "byzantiumBlock": 0
   },
   "difficulty": "400",
   "gasLimit": "200000000",
   "alloc": {
      "7b684d27167d208c66584ece7f09d8bc8f86ffff": { 
          "balance": "100000000000000000000000" 
      },
      "ae13d41d66af28380c7af6d825ab557eb271ffff": { 
          "balance": "120000000000000000000000" 
      }
   }
}
```

I did the following commands in sequence:

1. `geth --datadir ./myDataDir init ./myGenesis.json`
2. `geth --nodiscover --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir ./myDataDir --networkid 1111 console 2>> myEth.log`
3. `personal.newAccount()`
4. `eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)`
   I got balance 0.
   Then I did some mining.
5. `miner.setEtherbase(web3.eth.accounts[0])`
6. `miner.start()`
7. `eth.getBalance(eth.coinbase)`
   This gave me 318000000000000000000
8. `miner.stop()`

Now I created another account

9. `personal.newAccount()`
10. `eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[1])`
    I got balance 0.

My accounts are:
["0x72b04ad624b90739b68bbdbf0a1387738ef5d6d1", "0x520bb736d6340c4bb2279e6f6f6a2f74b90ac37c"]

Then I sent some ether from 1st account to 2nd one using the following:

11. `var sender = "0x72b04ad624b90739b68bbdbf0a1387738ef5d6d1"`
12. `var receiver = "0x520bb736d6340c4bb2279e6f6f6a2f74b90ac37c"`
13. `var amount = web3.toWei(0.0000001, "ether")`

I unlocked the 1st account:

14. `personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0])`

and then did the transaction:

15. `eth.sendTransaction({ from:sender, to:receiver, value:amount });`

It returned the transaction hash but the balance is still 0 in the 2nd account(0x520bb736d6340c4bb2279e6f6f6a2f74b90ac37c)

What am I missing here ? or the procedure is wrong ? Please help

Comment: It seems to be the correct approach. Can you provide the transaction receipt also? `eth.getTransactionReceipt`

Comment: Did you mine new blocks after sending the transaction? You need to mine a block with the transaction for it to be confirmed.

Comment: Thank you so much. Did mining after the transaction and the balance is updated.